# Store value of a callback function in Python

Tags: python, callback, ros

I am trying to store the content of a callback function, in order to access and manipulate the data within the script.
As far as I am concerned, the given function `.subscribe()` in my code below does not return anything (`None`). My function is only passed as a reference to the function as an argument. Is there a way to return the data from the function that calls my function?

My code is a simple example with **[roslibpy](https://roslibpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** (a library for Python that interacts with the open-source robotics framework **ROS** through Websockets). It is mentioned, that the data is published as a stream via a Websocket each time a message is published into the topic **/turtle1/pose**. My goal here is to return the data that is being published into the topic. The print command provides a nice visualization of the data, which just works fine.

```
import roslibpy
  
client = roslibpy.Ros(host='localhost', port=9090)
client.run()

def myfunc(msg):
    print(msg)
      
listener = roslibpy.Topic(client, '/turtle1/pose', 'turtlesim/Pose')

#my function is passed as an argument
listener.subscribe(myfunc)

try:
    while True:
         pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    client.terminate()
```

The `subscribe()` method in the **roslibpy** library is defined as follows:

```
def subscribe(self, callback):
    """Register a subscription to the topic.

    Every time a message is published for the given topic,
    the callback will be called with the message object.

    Args:
        callback: Function to be called when messages of this topic are published.
    """
    # Avoid duplicate subscription
    if self._subscribe_id:
        return

    self._subscribe_id = 'subscribe:%s:%d' % (
        self.name, self.ros.id_counter)

    self.ros.on(self.name, callback)
    self._connect_topic(Message({
        'op': 'subscribe',
        'id': self._subscribe_id,
        'type': self.message_type,
        'topic': self.name,
        'compression': self.compression,
        'throttle_rate': self.throttle_rate,
        'queue_length': self.queue_length
    }))
```

Is there common way to deal with such problems? Does it make more sense to store the output as an external source (e.g. *.txt*) and then access the source trough the script?

Comment: you could update a global variable in `myfunc` or put everything in a class and update an instance variable of that class in `myclass.myfunc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a Python class that acts like a function, that can modify its own state when called, by defining the magic `__call__` method. When `obj(whatever)` is done on a non-function `obj`, Python will run `obj.__call__(whatever)`. `subscribe` only needs its input to be callable; whether it is an actual function or an object with a `__call__` method does not matter to `subscribe`.

Here's an example of what you could do:

```
class MessageRecorder():
    def __init__(self):
        self.messages = []

    # Magic python 'dunder' method
    # Whenever a MessageRecorder is called as a function
    # This function defined here will be called on it
    # In this case, adds the message to a list of received messages
    def __call__(self, msg):
        self.messages.append(msg)

recorder = MessageRecorder()

# recorder can be called like a function
recorder("Hello")

listener.subscribe(recorder)

try:
    while True:
         pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    client.terminate()

"""Now you can do whatever you'd like with recorder.messages,
which contains all messages received before termination,
in order of reception. If you wanted to print all of them, do:"""
for m in recorder.messages:
    print(m)
```