# Receiving data in python callback function from dll

Tags: python, events, dll, callback, scope

I am writing a program in Python that communicates with a spectrometer from Avantes. There are some proprietary dlls available whose code I don't access to, but they have some decent documentation. I am having some trouble to find a good way to store the data received via callbacks.

### The proprietary  shared library

Basically, the dll contains a function that I have to call to start measuring and that receives a callback function that will be called whenever the spectrometer has finished a measurement. The function is the following:

```
int AVS_MeasureCallback(AvsHandle a_hDevice,void (*__Done)(AvsHandle*, int*),short a_Nmsr)
```

The first argument is a handle object that identifies the spectrometer, the second is the actual callback function and the third is the amount of measurements to be made.
The callback function will receive then receive another type of handle identifying the spetrometer and information about the amount of data available after a measurement.

### Python library

I am using a [library](https://github.com/MSLNZ/msl-equipment) that has Python wrappers for many equipments, including my spectrometer.

```
def measure_callback(self, num_measurements, callback=None):
    self.sdk.AVS_MeasureCallback(self._handle, callback, num_measurements)
```

And they also have defined the following decorator:

```
MeasureCallback = FUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(c_int32), POINTER(c_int32))
```

The idea is that when the callback function is finally called, this will trigger the `get_data()` function that will retrieve data from the equipment.

The recommended example is

```
@MeasureCallback
def callback_fcn(handle, info):
    print('The DLL handle is:', handle.contents.value)
    if info.contents.value == 0:  # equals 0 if everything is okay (see manual)
       print('  callback data:', ava.get_data())

ava.measure_callback(-1, callback_fcn)
```

### My problem

I have to store the received data in a 2D numpy array that I have created somewhere else in my main code, but I can't figure out what is the best way to update this array with the new data available inside the callback function.
I wondered if I could pass this numpy array as an argument for the callback function, but even in this case I cannot find a good way to do this since it is expected that the callback function will have only those 2 arguments.

---

### Edit 1

I found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278951/store-value-of-a-callback-function-in-python) but I am not sure it is the best way to do it. I'd rather not create a new class just to hold a single numpy array inside.

---

### Edit 2

I actually changed my mind about my approach, because inside my callback I'd like to do many operations with the received data and save the results in many different variables. So, I went back to the class approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278951/store-value-of-a-callback-function-in-python), where I would basically have a class with all the variables that will somehow be used in the callback function and that would also inherit or have an object of the class `ava`.

However, as shown in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259794/how-can-i-get-methods-to-work-as-callbacks-with-python-ctypes), the `self` parameter is a problem in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem with a solution envolving a new class and also a closure function to deal with the `self` parameter that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65174074/9811491). Besides that, another problem would appear by garbage collection of the new created method.

My final solution is:

```
class spectrometer():
        
        def measurement_callback(self,handle,info):
            if info.contents.value >= 0:  
                timestamp,spectrum = self.ava.get_data()
                self.spectral_data[self.spectrum_index,:] = np.ctypeslib.as_array(spectrum[0:pixel_amount])
                self.timestamps[self.spectrum_index] = timestamp
                self.spectrum_index += 1
        
        def __init__(self,ava):
            self.ava = ava
            self.measurement_callback = MeasureCallback(self.measurement_callback)
            
        def register_callback(self,scans,pattern_amount,pixel_amount):
            self.spectrum_index = 0
            self.timestamps = np.empty((pattern_amount),dtype=np.uint32)
            self.spectral_data = np.empty((pattern_amount,pixel_amount),dtype=np.float64)
            self.ava.measure_callback(scans, self.measurement_callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new class, you can use a function closure:

```
# Initialize it however you want
numpy_array = ... 

def callback_fcn(handle, info):
    # Do what you want with the value of the variable
    store_data(numpy_array, ...)

# After the callback is called, you can access the changes made to the object
print(get_data(numpy_array))
```

How this works is that when the `callback_fcn` is defined, it keeps a reference to the value of the variable `numpy_array`, so when it's called, it can manipulate it, as if it were passed as an argument to the function. So you get the effect of passing it in, without the callback caller having to worry about it.

Comment: I tried to use a function closure, but weirdly I couldn't access global scope variables such as numpy_array. Anyways, I actually thought a little bit more and I would actually need other arguments and the closure function would end up too complicated, so I switched to the class approach.

Comment: But the solution I first mentioned in my question did not work completely because ```self``` wouldn't work with my decorator. Eventually I found a solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259794/how-can-i-get-methods-to-work-as-callbacks-with-python-ctypes) .

Comment: You should post your particular solution as an answer, since it's likely the correct answer to your question, and mine doesn't solve the problem you had