# Store value of a callback in Python using asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to use Deepgram streaming speech recognition for a project. I can stream the transcribed text to the console using their quickstart demo code, but the text is printed from within a callback function. I would like to get the individual chunks of transcribed text out of the callback into a single string (or an array or whatever) so I can format longer pieces of the transcription before printing it.

Seems like a similar problem as [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66279927](this question), but I think my situation needs to be treated differently due to asyncio (or something else I am not understanding)

This works, but just dumps each little piece of transcribed text to the console:

```
from deepgram import Deepgram
import asyncio
import aiohttp

DEEPGRAM_API_KEY = '****'
URL = 'http://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_world_service'

async def main():
  deepgram = Deepgram(DEEPGRAM_API_KEY)

  # Create a websocket connection to Deepgram
  deepgramLive = await deepgram.transcription.live({ 'language': 'en-US' })

  # Listen for the connection to close
  deepgramLive.registerHandler(deepgramLive.event.CLOSE, lambda c: print(f'Connection closed with code {c}.'))

  # Listen for any transcripts received from Deepgram and write them to the console
  deepgramLive.registerHandler(deepgramLive.event.TRANSCRIPT_RECEIVED, print_transcript) # using anything more complex/persistent than print_transcript here throws 'raise AttributeError(name) from None' error

  # Listen for the connection to open and send streaming audio from the URL to Deepgram
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(URL) as audio:
      while True:
        data = await audio.content.readany()
        deepgramLive.send(data)

        # do more with the transcribed chunks here?

        if not data:
            break
  await deepgramLive.finish()


def print_transcript(json_data):
   print(json_data['channel']['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])


asyncio.run(main())
```

I tried using a class with a `__call__` method as in the other question and I tried messing with asyncio.Queue, but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their Python documentation is horrendous, so we have to check the source code. But it seems the [`LiveTranscription.register_handler`](https://github.com/deepgram/deepgram-python-sdk/blob/2.8.0/deepgram/transcription.py#L267) method expects the `handler` argument to be of type `EventHandler` as defined [here](https://github.com/deepgram/deepgram-python-sdk/blob/2.8.0/deepgram/_types.py#L254). That is just a function that can be called with one argument of any type and that returns `None` or an equivalent coroutine function.

This is still *very* badly typed because we have absolutely no idea what type of object this handler will receive in general. But judging from *your* code with that `print_transcript` function, you seem to be expecting a dictionary (or something similar).

If you want to store those objects rather than just printing and discarding, you have many options. One would be to write a handler function that takes some sort of data structure (a list for example) as an *additional* argument and stores those objects in that data structure instead of printing them, then use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) in your `main` function to pre-bind such a storage object to that function argument before passing the partially initialized function to `register_handler`.

Something like this:

```py
from functools import partial
from typing import Any


def store_data(data: Any, storage: list[Any]) -> None:
    storage.append(data)


async def main() -> None:
    ...
    storage = []
    handler = partial(store_data, storage=storage)
    deepgram_live.register_handler(deepgram_live.event.TRANSCRIPT_RECEIVED, handler)
```

Another almost equivalent option would be to define that handler function *inside* the `main` function and provide it access to a storage object from within that `main` function's scope:

```py
from typing import Any

async def main() -> None:
    ...
    storage = []

    def store_data(data: Any) -> None:
        storage.append(data)
    
    deepgram_live.register_handler(deepgram_live.event.TRANSCRIPT_RECEIVED, store_data)
```

You could indeed use an `asyncio.Queue` instead of a simple `list` if you want, but the principles of how you make the handler function *access* that queue object are still the same.

I don't use Deepgram, so I have not tested this, but at least from what I could gather from the poor documentation, the source, and your example, I think this should work.

Comment: That worked, thanks! The `partial` solution was complaining about `storage` not being callable, but just defining `store_data` inside `main` worked perfectly. (side note: 'Any' needs to be all lowercase 'any')

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the import. Of course it was supposed to be `typing.Any`. And the `partial` was a typo. It should work with `partial(store_data, storage=storage)`.